# Drawing graphics with C++ (How does this work?) (And tips for a faster compiler?)

Tags: c++, graphics, compilation, window

I've been making random stuff in Gamemaker and Flash for about 4-5 years now, but I've always wanted to write code in C++. (I don't want to use game engines, I am more interested in writing my own.)

My goal is to eventually write an engine in an early 3D style (I want to mimic that PSX look of low poly characters, low-res textures, 'swimming' textures and poly's etc.) just as a throwback to the games I used to play as a kid.

But I want to start out small.

After borrowing some books from the library about the basics and simple codes (which was a fun experience), I wanted to take it a little step further and find out how graphics work with C++. Not 3D graphics, just graphics in general. (Maybe a little sprite) I want to make something simple and get an insight on how this works.

I want to draw graphics in a new window (320x240, no anti-aliasing) and get rid of the console window. I'm a beginner, I don't really understand how this works, but from what I understand, C++ is just a programming language and I'll have to include something else (which I don't know) to draw the graphics.

I'm using Notepad++ and MinGW for compiling my code. (though compiling goes really slow. I'd love to know a better and faster, but free compiler that just like MinGW, works across more than one platform)

I hope someone could help me out.

Thanks,

~A very enthusiastic newbie (and modeller/artist/musician) with big ideas.

Comment: Your programming style affects you compilation time (for example, using forward declarations improves it). As for the graphics side of things, there's a LOT of choice, just google `C++ graphics library`.

Comment: Hey, welcome @user3450393! Perhaps a [search](https://www.google.com/#q=basic+C%2B%2B+%2Bgraphics+tutorials+mingw%7C%22cross+platform%22+opengl%7Cdirectx+2D%7C3D) would return some more relevant (and faster) results :) This question is a bit open ended and will likely receive varied and broad answers since it can be answered in many ways.

Comment: I'd also recommend getting a good grasp of C++ basics before diving into graphics. C++ can have a high learning curve itself (especially coming from GML or AS2/3) and trust me when I say graphics libraries have their own curve on top of that.

Comment: Thanks OMGtechy, for mentoining C++ Graphics Library. That was just what I was looking for. 
And Qix, I think I might start looking for a course on C++ game programming. Now that I look back on what I've written, I should have been more clear on what I wanted to ask.

Comment: @user3450393 and please, for the love of god, avoid Unity and the like. They're ok if you have a specialist, but they don't teach you C++ (don't teach you anything except how to use THEM specifically). And they force you to use all their features (performance drop).

Answer (score 1):

MinGW is a port of GCC, which works on all UNIX-like systems.
If you want a true cross-platform compiler, you can use LLVM/Clang (free & Open Source (BSD license)) or the Intel compiler (commercial, but faster).

To draw things, you can either: use native APIs (pain), use a graphical toolkit (DirectX, OpenGL...) (also pain), use a library (for 2D and handling of stuff, SDL is popular, but I like SFML more) (for 3D, you might consider GLFW).

Look at all of those, decide which ones you like more (they're all cross-platform) and read their documentation/API/Tutorials.

---

SFML API  example (direct answer to question on how to draw a sprite)

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(600,800), "Example!");//window information, can be more precise

    sf::Texture texture;//a texture for the sprite
    if(!texture.loadFromFile("MySprite.png")//load the texture
    {
        return 1;
    }
    sf::Sprite sprite(texture);//make the sprite from the texture

    while(window.isOpen())//until window dies
    {
        sf::Event event; //event handling
        while(window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();// let window close if it's closed
        }
        window.clear(); //clear screen
        window.draw(sprite);//draw the sprite wherever it is
        window.display();//switch buffers
    }
}
```

---

Also, a small side note. Development (that's fully cross platform) tends to work better on UNIX (because you don't have to go through the massive pain of setting up on windows, remember how painful ANY library is to get working?) I suggest you also look at CMake (or any of its alternatives), vim (or geany, if vim is too hardcore) and compiling through the command line :)

Comment: [SFML](http://sfml-dev.org) and [SDL](http://libsdl.org) are both great starting points for graphics. SFML is simpler than SDL in my opinion and has a great community for help.

Comment: @Qix I prefer SFML. It loses a bit of efficiency, but is true OO and has more features overall.

Comment: Is there a free version of the Intel Compiler available? What would be the difference? 

Do I have to download these graphical toolkits, or do they already with my graphics driver? (Aren't DirectX and OpenGL APIs?) And is there anything else I have to do to include them to my project? 

But thanks a lot, Shingetsu, this reply has helped me quite a lot to get an idea of how this works. (Do you happen to know if these also handle sound?)

Comment: @user3450393 OpenGL does not handle sound, OpenAL (another library does). DirectX has a family member called DirectSound that handles sound. Both SFML and SDL handle sound. There is no free Intel compiler, but Clang is pretty damn good. The difference is the way they report stuff. All those libraries need to be installed (one way or another) and linked against your program, this is why I told you to look up compiling through the command line. To link a library on windows, you go through about 24 steps. On *nix you just add -lLibrary-Name (e.g. -lSFML) to the compile command, if it's installed.

Comment: @Shingetsu (Sorry, I didn't see the second part of your reply after the code) So I assume compiling through command lines was what I already have been doing? (writing "g++ main.cpp -o main" in CMD using the MinGW compiler) correct me if I'm wrong.

What exactly is the difference between Vim and Notepad++? 

From what I understand you will need libraries for graphics, sound and other important parts that make up a game. And that has to be compiled using a compiler. C++ writes the instructions on how these should behave and what to include.

Comment: @user3450393 mingw is a _pretty cheap_ port of gcc/g++. Yes that is what you have been doing, but what I mean is doing it through a BUILD TOOL. (look up CMake to get the idea, it automates it). And um... vim is special. (look it up! just google vim)